# React Native Splash Screen status bar Android

Tags: react-native, splash-screen

What I am trying to accomplish is to customized the status bar of the splash screen.

Following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-splash-screen) link I added this line in **MainActivity.java**:

```
  //Imports
  package com.myapp;

  import android.os.Bundle;
  import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
  import org.devio.rn.splashscreen.SplashScreen; 


  public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme);  // here 
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
```

But as a result I get this error in console:

[image]

Am I missing any imports?

Answer (score 2):

library documentation is out of date.

To make the code work the correct line is:

```
SplashScreen.show(this, R.style.SplashScreenTheme, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try below**

```
import React from 'react'
import { View, StatusBar, Text } from 'react-native'

export default function SplashScreen() {
        return (
            <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center', }}>
    
                <StatusBar backgroundColor='black' barStyle='light-content' />
    
                <Text>
                    SplashScreen.js
                </Text>
    
            </View>
        )
    }
```

**More about customize statusbar** https://reactnative.dev/docs/statusbar

**Different status bar configuration based on route**
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/status-bar/

**Medium Example** https://medium.com/simform-engineering/react-native-statusbar-theme-based-on-screen-cad263e6c8bc

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me, but this doesn't solve the actual problem. The point is that splash screen has kind of it's own 'status bar' and it doesn't care about the <StatusBar /> component or StatusBar.setStyle('...').

Comment: Okay if possible can please share your code.